# How does a discordance test work?

Tags: correlation, paired-comparisons, concordance

Could someone explain how the discordance test works (and what it actually is)? The explanations I found online are unclear:

> [...] the concordance test can be viewed as the evaluation of the existence of positive reasons supporting the sentence "x is at least as good as y", while the discordance test can be viewed as the evaluation of the existence of negative reasons against the same sentence.
>   [Source](http://l1.lamsade.dauphine.fr/~tsoukias/papers/condis08.pdf)

and:

> discordance = nd = the number of pairs for which the model predicts higher probability of a severe accident for the member of the pair that had the less severe accident. 
>   [Source](http://ntl.bts.gov/DOCS/98133/ch05/body_ch05_04.html)

For some reason those explanations make me think of rejecting a null hypothesis (although I'm aware it's a lot more than just that).